# Get index of first element that is not zero in a __m256 variable

Tags: c++, c, sse, simd, avx

```
__m256  dst = _mm256_cmp_ps(value1, value2, _CMP_LE_OQ);
```

If `dst` is `[0,0,0,-nan, 0,0,0,-nan];`
I want to be able to know the first `-nan` index, in this case `3` without doing a for loop with `8` iterations.
Is this possible?

Comment: Think of the compare-result as integers or masks, even though it's in a `__m256`.  It's 0 or all-ones, which is 2's complement -1 = unsigned 0xFFFFFFFF.  I mean yes if interpreted as IEEE binary32, they are the bit patterns for 0 or -NaN, but that's rarely how you want to use them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would [`movmskps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movmskps) the result of the comparison and then do a [bitscan forward](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bsf).

Using intrinsics (this works with gcc/clang, see [here for alternatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set#Tool_and_library_support)):

```
int pos = __builtin_ctz(_mm256_movemask_ps(dst));
```

Note that the result of `bsf` is unspecified if no bit is set. To work around this you can, e.g., write this to get `8`, if no other bit is set:

```
int pos = __builtin_ctz(_mm256_movemask_ps(dst) | 0x100);
```

Comment: Note that on newer CPUs, such as, e.g., Intel Haswell or newer, you can use `_tzcnt_u32()` instead of `__builtin_ctz()`. Intrinsic `_tzcnt_u32()` can be used with all major compilers (gcc, icc, clang, MSVC). It maps to the `tzcnt` instruction, which is well defined for zero inputs too.